# How to create elements with zeep from WSDL?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep

How to create elements with zeep from WSDL?

While I can look up types by their namespace and name I cannot create elemtents the same way. zeep provides an overview of global elements:

```
Global elements:
     ns1:Request(FooBar: {Parms: {CorrelationID: xsd:string, ...
     ns1:Response(FooBar: {Data: {CorrelationID: xsd:string, ...
```

I tried to retrieve a type like this:

```
request_type = client.get_type("ns1:Request")
```

but I get the following error:

```
No type 'Request' in namespace http://ws.example.com/FooBar. Available types are:  -
```

As there are no types listed, how can I construct an element with zeep? I need the element as a parameter for a service operation.

Comment: Can you share the WSDL? Alternatively, instead of creating an object with client.get_type(), have you tried sending a dictionary instead?

Comment: I cannot share the WSDL as this would reveal who my client is. Maybe I can create a reduced example. I will try a dictionary.